# PHP - Auto fill variables to function?

Tags: php

I set a lot of variables as public, we can use for example:

```
    public $id; 
    public $title;
    public $description;
```

I have example function:

```
    public static function create($db, $data)
    {
        $id = $data->id; 
        $title= $data->title; 
        $description= $data->description;
        ...
    }
```

and inside that a example query

```
if($db->query('INSERT INTO '.menu::$table.'(id, title, description) 
        VALUES ( :id, :title, :description )'  
        , array( ':id'=>$id,':title'=>$title, ':description'=>$description, )))
```

and more and more functions with use names: "id", "title", "description" in other way.

Is any possibility to have that properties will be "filled" in many places in functions without manual copy, paste? 
I thought about variables array but how to iterable it in function arguments etc?

Comment: Don't create more variables for no reason, just use `$data->id` etc directly in your call to `$db->query`.

Comment: Ok, but anyway I need use it in function few times, its not possibility to use something like:
$fields = ['id', 'title','description']
if($db->query('INSERT INTO '.example::$table.'($fields)  VALUES ($fields )',
 , array( ':id'=>$field,...)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to iterate over a class' public properties:

```php
class Utilities
{
    public static function getPublicProperties($object)
    {
        $reflectionObject = new ReflectionObject($object);
        $reflectionProperties = $reflectionObject->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);

        $properties = [];

        foreach ($reflectionProperties as $reflectionProperty) {
            if (! $reflectionProperty->isStatic()) {
                $properties[] = $reflectionProperty->getName();
            }
        }

        return $properties;
    }

    public static function create($db, $data)
    {
        foreach (self::getPublicProperties($data) as $var) {
            ${$var} = $data->{$var};
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use the keys of the array returned by [get_class_vars()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php), but be careful that this function is context-sensitive: it will return the public properties when called from outside the class, as well as protected and private properties when used from inside. If your class only has public properties, then both approaches are equivalent.

---

### Now, should you do this?

Probably not. While convenient, it makes your code very obscure, and you lose any static analysis capability from your IDE or external tools.

- For database mapping, you should use an ORM ([Doctrine](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html) for example).
- For custom logic, it's fine to have code like the one you wrote above:

  ```php
  $id          = $data->id; 
  $title       = $data->title; 
  $description = $data->description;
  ...
  ```